# "functions" in a dialog box procedure

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I'm noticing a need for functions in my dialog box procedures. For example, there are multiple buttons I can hit which require other controls to be updated in the same exact way. Right now I'm just repeating the same code in the appropriate places.

Are global dialogbox "helper" functions a common solution to this problem?

Comment: More information about the framework you are coding in would help answer.  Generally: if it were C, then yes...global helper functions would be the way to go.  But as you tagged this C++, it would be typical to have a class representing the dialog box and the "helper functions" would just be private methods of that class.

Comment: Sorry, it's a native Windows C++ program but I'm directly interacting with the Win32 API to create dialog boxes, controls, etc. I believe the dialogproc needs to be static, so I could put it in its own class with some private static member functions. At the moment the static dialogproc is defined in my main app class.

Comment: I'd generally suggest using some abstraction layer ([WTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library), maybe?)  But what a lot of these C++ bridges do is stuff the object pointer into the window with `SetWindowLong()` and `GWL_USERDATA`, and then pull the pointer out during callbacks with `GetWindowLong`...quickly transitioning from a stub (static method, or whatever) into calling class methods on the object it stowed away associated with the HWND.

Answer (score 0):

You could factor the common functionality into a separate class or module.  Let your dialog class inherit from the factored class or call the freestanding functions.

I call this process Software Evolution:  *refactoring* common pieces into separate modules that two or more software units can use.